# Facebook Events tab link does not appear on mobile

Tags: facebook, events, mobile, hyperlink, share

I shared the link to my brand's "Facebook Events" tab in a status update and the link doesn't work on mobile.

For instance, **https://www.facebook.com/[Brand Name]/events** is included in the post copy, and it works on desktop but on mobile I get a "The page you requested was not found."

Is there a hack to this, or a way to share the Facebook Events page link to work for all platforms?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So, what is your programming question?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I looked up the Facebook "Event" page on my phone and copied the URL that was being referenced on my PHONE. I then pasted that URL in the HTML and boom! It now works. :-)